# Calculating the conditional probability Prob(A|B)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

> There are 6 women philosophy graduate students in the philosophy
>   department, 12 women philosophers, and 20 philosophy graduate
>   students. What is the probability that a philosopher is a graduate
>   student, given that she is a woman? What is the probability that a
>   philosopher is a woman, given than (s)he is a graduate student?

I am having trouble understanding how to calculate this.

For the first question, do I divide 6 (the event of being a philosophy graduate student) into 18 (the event of being a woman)? Or do I divide 20 (the event of being a graduate student) into 18 (the event of being a woman)?

For the second question, do I divide 18 (the event of being a woman) into 20 (the event of being a graduate)? Why? Or am I completely wrong and need to calculate the probability of being a woman philosopher (18/38) and the probability of being a grad student (20/38) separately?

How would I solve this problem???

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  When asking a question, please include a look at what you have tried / where you are getting stuck.  You'll find you get much more help that way, because we know exactly what idea is giving you trouble!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding how to calculate this. For the first question, do I divide 6 (the event of being a philosophy graduate student) into 18 (the event of being a woman)? Or do I divide 20 (the event of being a graduate student) into 18 (the event of being a woman)? For the second question, do I divide 18 (the event of being a woman) into 20 (the event of being a graduate)? Why? Or am I completely wrong and need to calculate the probability of being a woman philosopher (18/38) and the probability of being a grad student (20/38) separately? How would I solve this problem???

Comment: I've added your comment above to your question.  Note: it is possible for you to [edit] your question.

Comment: It is clear that they count philosophy grad students as philosophers. In England, even undergraduate math majors are called mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the definition $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.  In a finite situation, this becomes $P(A|B)=\dfrac{N(A\cap B)}{N(B)}$.

Let us set $A=$ Woman and $B=$ Graduate Student.

Then your first question is $P(B|A)=\dfrac{6}{12}=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

You should be able to figure out your second question using the same reasoning.